# Classloading in tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

Class-Loading mechanism inside app server is a common source of confusing for developer; that's why I wonder to ask a question about this mechanism in tomcat 7 server :
I have a web app sample.war which depends on jgroups lib,

- Which is the best place to put the jgroups.jar **tomcat/lib** or **tomcat/webapps/sample.war/WEB-INF/lib**?
- If I have to version of jgroups (lets say 2.7.x and 3.x)
- When I put jgroups 3.x  under **tomcat/lib** and jgroups 2.7.x under **tomcat/webapps/sample.war/WEB-INF/lib**, so which version will be used by my appplication in runtime?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Following the Tomcat best practices (that is, duplicate all your jars in your apps) and the official documentation (which depends on your tomcat version), you must put all your jars under your **/WEB-INF/lib** folder.

But, if you need to share jars between applications you **mustn't** put any jar in **tomcat/lib** for that purpose you have the **tomcat/shared** folders and **tomcat/common** folders, configurable in the **cont/catalina.properties** Which folder use, it depends if your environment is Linux or Windows.

[Here](http://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-classpath) you can find a nice tutorial about.